# How can I allow spaces in a Django username?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to allow spaces in usernames in my Django app.  This is from my form:

```
class SignUpForm(django.forms.ModelForm):
...
    username = django.forms.RegexField(
       regex=r'^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z -]{1,29}$'
```

I want username to start with a letter.  After that I allow letters and spaces and hyphens.  Somehow the form fails validation with "John Smith" and I have no idea why.  Is there a restriction on spaces somewhere else?

Comment: You can try using the `setattr` method instead

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space in the regex? ie: '\ '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the django auth user is based on an abstract user class (django.contrib.auth.models). Your bound form may be valid, but if you try to save the user object validation fails.

Have a look at the source from django.contrib.auth.models regarding the username:

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
admin-compliant permissions.

Username, password and email are required. Other fields are optional.
"""
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and '
                    '@/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[
            validators.RegexValidator(r'^[\w.@+-]+$', _('Enter a valid username.'), 'invalid')
        ])
```

Hope this sheds some light on it.